# How to use devtools to explore blind spots in react scripting?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-devtools

I have this simple select component and I am profiling using the query params `react_perf`. But I can't understand what is happening after the `render` when updating it. As you can see the render take about 0.17ms of the total 18.46ms that `SimpleSelect[update]`. What is happening in the other time?

[image]

Comment: Enable chrome://flags/#enable-devtools-experiments and restart the browser, open devtools, its settings, experiments, tap Shift key 6 times (close any possible OS dialogs and continue), enable `Timeline: show all events` and `Timeline: V8 Runtime blabla`, redo the recording.

Comment: Also, take a look *below* the flame-chart: maybe the time is spent uploading the frame to GPU.

Comment: @wOxxOm http://imgur.com/a/sfLEZ. Not a super expert with devTools, but it seems that the other time is actually spent in the GPU..

Comment: Yep, it's GPU. Click that block and the preceding `Paint` block in flame-chart: I guess a large area is being updated. You'll have to rework your layout and/or CSS to minimize the area that needs repainting.

Comment: @wOxxOm I don't really need it. The whole it takes barely 20ms, so it's good this way. I was just curious where time was going.  You can post it as an answer